# is there any known bundler which includes only code which is actually used

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundler

The title says it all.

**Example:**

```
var Vec2 = require('vec2')

var a = Vec2(3,4)
var b = Vec2(4,1)
var c = a.substract(b)

// ...
```

The `vec2` npm package is really huge and includes all functionality you need to play with 2d vectors. However only a small portion is used in my project. When I browserify my code the whole package is included albeit I only need a few parts

Comment: The term you're looking for is [tree-shaking](http://moduscreate.com/webpack-2-tree-shaking-configuration) and is/will be in webpack 2.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the tree-shaking feature mentioned by Andy is for ES2015+.

Comment: @Andy I read through the link you provided but its not exatly what I looking for. Tree-shaking only elliminates the modules which are exported but not imported. In case of Vec2 there is only one export which includes the whole object. All methods are bind to the prototype of that object and therefore exported along with everything

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I guess it would be the same issue as with test-coverage of the code. But with another purpose.